# Address of array VS pointer-to-pointer : Not the same?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I was working with pointers and came up with a problem.
So far I know that when we create an array of any data type, then the name of the array is actually a pointer (maybe static pointer) pointing towards the very first index of the array. correct?

So what I'm trying to achieve is to create another pointer that may hold the address of the array name(i.e a pointer towards another pointer which in my case is the array name)

For Example:

```
char name[] = "ABCD";  // name holding the address of name[0]
char *ptr1 = name;     // When is this possible?
char **ptr2 = &name;   // Why not this?
                       // It gives an error: cannot convert char(*)[5] to char**
```

I'm using Code Blocks as IDE.

Comment: No, No, No.  An array is not a pointer.  It can decay to a pointer when passed to a function but it is not a pointer.  Do not think of arrays as pointers.

Comment: So you mean when I wrote char *ptr1 = name;  it actually did char *ptr1 = &name[0]; ? and name itself is not a separate pointer variable ?

Comment: Arrays are not "strict" pointers. Pointer is some memory location that holds an address. When you use an array compiler just knows what it's address is, but it isn't stored anywhere and cannot be overwritten. Your second statement implied that you could do *ptr2 = somethingelse, which cannot be done.

Comment: @nsilent22: What do you mean with "strict"? An array is **not** a pointer - fullstop. It has different properties and does not behave like a pointer. It is just **converted** to a pointer **to the first element** (but not to the array!) for most usages (there are actually three exceptions). To get a pointer to the array, you still use the `&` operator.

Comment: @Ahmed.J Yes.  That is the same thing.

Comment: @Olaf: What I meant was exactly what I wrote.

Comment: @nsilent22: Maybe what youi meant. But you should have been more clear in your comment.

Comment: @AhmedJ That is a good way to think of it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I seem to remember Olaf once arguing that arrays *are* pointers, but I'm probably wrong about that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the info. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @NathanOliver actually arrays names and functions names are pointers that **point** to the first very byte. they are surely not variable they are locked to their data and can not be assigned new values. but you can assign  their address to an other pointer without using the '&' operator.

Comment: @milevyo But an array is not a pointer.  Too many problems come from thinking that they are so we just need to stop thinking that way.

Comment: @NathanOliver i know what you mean, and you probably you know what i mean. indeed they are pointers, and it is true, they are not. all depend on the point of view.

Comment: @milevyo Function-to-pointer and array-to-pointer are implicit conversions. Implicit conversion does not imply that a value of one type *is* a value of a different type. Analogously, you can write `int x = 3; float y = x;`, but that does not mean that an `int` is a `float`. And that names would *be* something is nonsense. Names don't exist, only the objects they refer to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo my point of view is how things are stored in memory, and how to access them. your point of view is c typing.

Comment: @milevyo: Arrays are not stored as pointers in memory, ever.  (There is one quirky case where function parameters that look like arrays are actually pointers, but - those aren't actually arrays )]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** Arrays are not pointers.

In your code, `&name` is a pointer to *the array of 5 `char`s*. This is not the same as a pointer to *a pointer to `char`*. You need to change your code to

```
 char (*ptr2)[5] = &name;
```

or,

```
char (*ptr2)[sizeof(name)] = &name;
```

FWIW, in some cases (example, passing an array as a function argument), the array name *decays* to the pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: instead of using `5` shouldn't we use `sizeof(name)`?

Comment: Two questions: 1) What is TL;DR and 2) Did you mean array of 5 `char`s?

Comment: @NathanOliver Better one, actually :)

Comment: @FiddlingBits 1) short answer.  2) my bad, corrected. :)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh  char (*ptr2)[5] = &name  means ptr2 as a single pointer or [5] specifies ptr2 as an array of 5 pointers ?

Comment: @Ahmed.J As I mentioned, `ptr2` will be ___a___ pointer to the array of 5 `char`s. :)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Adding that ptr2 will at a time point to the first char variable just like name is doing right? because even if ptr2 is a pointer to 5 chars , will ptr2 hold the collective address of 5 chars (don't know if that's even possible) or its just a way of expressing to match data type to just satisfy the compiler because as far as I know a pointer holds the address of a single item. That can be a variable,pointer,object,structure etc

Comment: @Ahmed.J: `ptr2` is not a pointer to the first `char` variable (or in fact any `char` variable). It is a pointer to the entire array.

Comment: @Ahmed.J an array type is a derived type. It's still a _type_, as a whole.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Much thanks for all your answers and sorry to make it a long post.                                                                                                                                   Just  One last question that after using what you suggested. when i write cout << **ptr2;  It gives me the letter 'A' as output. What does this implies that ptr2 was pointing towards something and that something was pointing towards the first element of the array "ABCD" which is 'A'

Comment: @Ahmed.J basically, yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pointer-to-pointer, you can use this:

```
int main(void){
  char name[] = "ABCD";
  char *ptr1 = name;
  char **ptr2 = &ptr1;
  std::cout << *ptr1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << **ptr2 << std::endl;
}
```

cheers.

Comment: Yes, that's one way out of this mess but I was actually trying to understand that why what I am trying to do is not possible.